# Nuxt error when running command: npm run dev

Tags: javascript, npm, nuxt.js, cockpit-cms

When I try to run the command "npm run dev" for my nuxt.js-app, I get following error message:

> This dependency was not found:
>
> - *C:\Users\mainuser\nuxt-app.nuxt\client.js in multi eventsource-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&path=%2F__webpack_hmr%2Fclient&name=client ./.nuxt/client.js

What cause could that have? I've installed the nuxt-app with axios, dotenv and eslint...

I hope someone is able to help me! Thanks

Comment: How did you started your project ? Have you run `npm i` or `yarn` at the same level that your `package.json` ?

Comment: I started like this: npm init nuxt-app project-name

Comment: Did you chose `yarn` or `npm` ?

Comment: I chose **yarn**

Comment: Which version do you have with `create-nuxt-app -v` ? Give us a full list of the selected features please. It's working fine on my side.

Comment: npm create-nuxt-app returns 6.14.10
In my nuxt.config.js file I have Axios.js as a plugin and a module, dotenv as a module and the following build:

` build: {
    extend(config, ctx) {
      
      if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        })
      }
    }
  }`

What else do you need?

Comment: Try running it again with `npx create-nuxt-app` and give us the list of all your available choices as displayed here: https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app#features-tada

Comment: Here are the choices I've made:

Programming language: JavaScript
Package manager: Npm
UI framework: None
Nuxt.js modules: Axios - Promise based HTTP client
Linting tools: ESLint, Prettier
Testing framework: None
Rendering mode: Universal (SSR / SSG)
Deployment target: Static (Static/JAMStack hosting)
Development tools: (None)
Continuous integration: None
Version control system: None

But maybe the error causes a mistake in this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@marco.jacobs/building-a-visual-website-with-nuxt-js-cockpit-cms-part-1-intro-and-setup-aab007855e4)

Comment: Edit your initial question next time, less cluncky and everybody can see it ! :D So, you chose `npm` and not `yarn` during the install. And yeah, the `create-nuxt-app` is working properly here. The issue is coming from the tutorial. At this point, the faster and most efficient thing would be to provide us a repo with your **exact** configuration (minus the env variables ofc).